# Android Studio Onclick Open Navigation Item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm new in Android Studio. I'm just confused with linking a navigation drawer with a button.

I have this onclicklistener:

```
    public void clickFunc(View view) {
       //codehere
      i.add(new NavItem("Tip Us", R.drawable.ic_details, NavItem.ITEM, WebviewFragment.class, "http://www.google.com"));
    }
```

When I click in a button I want to go to the navigation drawer.

I've just downloaded a project that fits my need but it uses navigation drawer and I want to use the button as a menu (not as a navigation drawer)

Anyone knows how to do it?